# How to insert border around text in a Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to insert a border around my text similar to the image I placed attached.

Thank you very much!

Executable code below.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
                        title="Test", collapsible = TRUE,
                        
                        tabPanel("",
                                 
                                 div(
                                   style = 
                                     "height: 80px; background-color: #02BE7F; width: 100%; position: absolute; right:0;",
                                   h2(HTML("Project <b>Description</b>"), 
                                      style="text-align:center;color: white"),
                                   hr(),
                                   
                                   div(
                                     style = "width: 70%; margin: auto;",
                                     h2(HTML("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                                      Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s"), 
                                        style="text-align:justify")),
                                   tags$style(".navbar {margin-bottom: 0;}")
                                 )
                                 
                        ))



server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try to add the border to the `div` style? For example, `border-style: solid; border-color: black;`

Comment: I tried, but I think I missed something. Could show where to insert? By the way ​​I would like to use this border from the second div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the border to the `div` by adding the border properties (e.g. `style = "border-style: solid; border-color: black;",`

Using your code

```
div( style = "border-style: solid; border-color: black;",
   h2(HTML("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s"), style="text-align:justify"))
```

[image]

Comment: Note that `HTML()` is useless here.  And I would some left and right paddings to the `h2` style: `style="text-align:justify; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;"`.